Sobolev embedding theorem on the torus
In his lecture notes at https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254a.1.01w/notes2.dvi, Terence Tao proves the following (non-endpoint) Sobolev embedding theorem:
Let $1 \le p < q \le \infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{q}$. Then
$$
\|f\|_{L^q(\bf{R}^n)} \lessapprox \|f\|_{L^p(\bf{R}^n)} + \|\nabla f\|_{L^p(\bf{R}^n)}.
$$
I would like to know if an analogous theorem exists for the torus ${\bf{T}}^n = {\bf{R}}^n/{\bf{Z}}^n$. I looked online but could not find analogues for this specific embedding theorem, however it looks to me like it should exist. In particular I am interested in the case $q = \infty$, $p=2$ and $n>2$, which would be quite useful to bound periodic functions. Furthermore, I would like to know the dependency of the implicit constants with $n$ for the torus.

Sobolev functions on the flat $n$-torus can be viewed as weakly differentiable and $1$-periodic functions on $\mathbb R^n$. You can then apply the full-space inequality to $f$ multiplied by a smooth cutoff $\chi$ that is identically one on the unit cube $Q = (0,1)^n$. This argument shows that the constant will scale in $n$ similarly to the constant from the full space case (but the sharp dependence is complicated).

The inequality on $p,q,n$ is wrong. It should read
$$
\frac1p - \frac1n < \frac1q,
$$
which is clear from the proof in Tao's notes.
This inequality now gives an upper bound on $q$, which is what one would expect for such inequalities.
You can also check Sobolev embedding theorems and Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality.

Honestly, I would not be surprised, if this result is only true if $\frac1p-\frac1n=\frac1q$.

Well spotted, I guess that teaches me to always check the proof no matter who writes it. Accepting since, with the correct inequality, the equivalent result on the torus is easy to locate.

See Lemma $2.1$ and Corollary $2.2$ in $[1]$. In such paper, the authors proved similar inequality as you want in $n$ - dimensional bounded domains of cone-type $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n$ - dimensional torus is a bounded domain of cone-type) to the spaces $H^s(\Omega)$. Moreover, the authors proved for $s \in (0,1)$ by using several general inequalities in $[2]$. So, I believe that the inequality you want can follow similarly to Lemma $2.1$ and Corollary $2.2$, for the particular case $s=1$.
$[1]$ Bittencourt Moraes, G., Borluk, H., de Loreno, G., Muslu, G. and Natali, F., Orbital stability of periodic standing waves for the cubic fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation. J. Differential Equations $341$ $(2022), 263-291$.
$[2]$ Triebel, H., Interpolation theory, function spaces, differential operators. North-Holland Publishing Co., Amsterdam-New York, $1978.$
For more general inequalities for general Sobolev spaces, see $[3]$.
$[3]$ Amann, H., Compact embeddings of vector-valued Sobolev and Besov spaces. Glas. Mat. Ser. III $35 (2000), 161-177.$
